# HttpWebRequest versus browser request

Tags: c#

I used to retrieve data from a site using a c# program.(nseindia.com) however recently NSE made some changes so that any request from any program is responded with a “403 Forbidden Error”. Can anyone tell me a way to make the request from the program identical to that from the browser. I tried setting the userAgent property but thats not working. The code is pasted below.

```
string DownloadData(string CompanyName)
{
    string address = string.Format(@"http://www.nseindia.com");
    //http://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?dataType=priceVolumeDeliverable&symbol=abb&
    //http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/01-12-2008-TO-29-12-2010ABBALLN.csv
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3

    string strData = "";
    try
    {
        request.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        System.Text.Encoding ec = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, ec);
        strData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (strData.Contains("Error"))
        {
            Exception e = new Exception(strData);
            throw e;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    return strData;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to request another url on another web site (say, http://www.google.com for instance). Maybe your corporate policies have changed, and you are not allowed no more to do direct http request without using a proxy.

Comment: Yes when i tried google it worked fine. Thankyou for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try setting the `Accept` HTTP header**; e.g.:

```
request.Accept = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml";
```

I arrived at this suggestion by running Fiddler2 (as suggested in a comment to another answer) in order to see how my browser (Firefox 4 Beta) makes the HTTP request to the website you mentioned.

I then set all headers in the code and eliminated one by one. As soon as I removed the `Accept` header, the `403` status code was returned.

Exact request made by my browser:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.nseindia.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b8) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0b8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
```

PS: The other URIs you mention in the comments seem to be invalid. One is incomplete and yields a `500 Internal Server Error`, the other yields a `404 Not Found` response.

Comment: THANK YOU stakx it worked!                                                     The other uri,s were incomplete. I have included the actual ones.

http://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolCount.jsp?symbol=ABB
http://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?dataType=priceVolumeDeliverable&symbol=abb&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=2&series=ALL&dateRange=day&fromDate=01-12-2008&toDate=29-12-2010
http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/01-12-2008-TO-29-12-2010ABBALLN.csv

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to spy your browser to see exactly the requests sent and responses received.

There is numerous addins for that, depending on your browser.

Comment: i tried that using tamper data on firefox but how do i spy the request sent from the program so that i can compare both requests.

Comment: It's a bit of a trick. You can modify your HOSTS file to make www.nseindia.com point on localhost, set up a tool like SocketWorkbench to listen on your port 80 and relay connection to the real ip address of www.nseindia.com. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set credentials as default like this

```
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

or

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
request.Credentials = nc;
```

if you need username password to access that web page

or an another option is to use `WebBrowser` control ;)

Comment: Tried Fiddler, nice tool Thanks.